# Angular and PouchDBFind plugin

Tags: angular, typescript, pouchdb, typescript-typings

I have an angular application in which I want to use PouchDB with the PouchDBFind plugin.

I've already gotten PouchDB to work. But I can't figure out how I use the PouchDB Plugin.

Example database setup:

```
constructor() {
    this.db = new PouchDB('exampleDb');
    this.db.createIndex({
        index: {fields: ['number', 'name']}
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```

I always get this error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: this.db.createIndex is not a function 
TypeError: this.db.createIndex is not a function
```

This is how my import statements are:

```
import * as PouchDB from 'pouchdb';
import * as PouchFind from 'pouchdb-find';
PouchDB.plugin(PouchFind);
```

I don't get any errors here.

I've already read about another import alternative, but this does **not** work:

```
import PouchDB from 'pouchdb';
import PouchFind from 'pouchdb-find';
```

I get this error:

```
"pouchdb-find" has no default export
```

I have installed the typings.
So here are my package.json dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@types/pouchdb": "6.1.1",
    "@types/pouchdb-find": "^0.10.1",
    "pouchdb": "^6.2.0",
    "pouchdb-find": "^6.3.4"
},
```

So how do I get the PouchDBFind plugin to work?
If any more information are required, please notice me.

Thanks in advance!

**Edit**:
After locking the versions to...

```
"pouchdb": "6.3.4",
"pouchdb-find": "6.3.4",
```

... I get the following warning after the webpack compilation:

```
WARNING in ./src/app/services/example-db/example-db.service.ts
17:8-22 "export 'plugin' (imported as 'PouchDB') was not found in 'pouchdb'
```

And in the browser console:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2_pouchdb__.plugin is not a function
TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2_pouchdb__.plugin is not a function
```

When I comment the `PouchDB.plugin(PouchFind)` line, the warning is gone but the error in the console remains. It just says that it doesn't have a constructor.

**Edit**: It is an angular-cli project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you lock your versions to ...

```
"pouchdb": "6.3.4",
"pouchdb-find": "6.3.4"
```

... and try again with the following?

```
import PouchFind from 'pouchdb-find';
import PouchDB from 'pouchdb-browser';

PouchDB.plugin(PouchFind);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have updated my questions. And i still have to import like the following:
import * as PouchDB from 'pouchdb'. import PouchDB from 'pouchdb' says that there is no default export

Comment: After uninstall the typings and reinstall pouchdb and pouchdb-find, I could import it as you suggested and everythings working. Thanks!

Comment: thanks you very much! this issue has already been bothering me for days 2 weeks ago - now I finally got my app running again :)

Comment: I tried those imports and im getting a compiler warning which stops the app from starting: **"export 'plugin' (imported as 'PouchDB') was not found in 'pouchdb-browser'**